# How to click on ui-sref set on button in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

```
<button class="button button-clear button-stable link" type="button" ui-sref="login">Login</button>

var link =  element(by.css('[ui-sref="login"]'));
link.click();
```

It will through error,

```
Failed: unknown error: Element <button class="button button-clear button-stable link ng-binding" type="button" ui-sref="login" href="#/login">...</button> is not clickable at point (179, 559). Other element would receive the click: <div class="loading-container visible active">...</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what `loading-container` is, but I'm guessing thats an overlay until your app is ready?  Wait for that to disappear before clicking.

Comment: No any overlay exists

Comment: ok well what is `loading-container` then?  seems to be on top of that button

Comment: This means there is a element on top of it which will receive the click and you should be clicking that element

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, there is a loading container that is hovering the element at the time it is clicked. Assuming that this loading container is a temporary thing, you should be able to make it work by adding an extra Explicit Wait which would waiting for "clickability" of the element:

```
var link = $('[ui-sref=login]');
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(link), 5000);
link.click();
```